# How to disable DNS Identity check on server

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, dns, certificate

I have self-hosted WCF service and several thousand client installations. 
New server certificate has different DNS name (*.mydomain.com instead mydomain.com), that’s the reason  DNS Identity has stopped working. Is there any way to cancel certificate validation by changing ONLY server side code/confg?

**Client**

```
   var binding = new NetTcpBinding
    {
        Security =
        {
            Mode = SecurityMode.Transport,
            Transport = {ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None}
        }
    };

    _proxyClientHost = new ChannelFactory<IMyClientApp>(binding, 
                                                        new EndpointAddress(new Uri("myservice.mydomain.com"),
                                                        EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("*.mydomain.com")));
```

**Server**

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyClientApp));
_serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "Certificate ThmubPrint Value …");
_serviceHost.Open();
```

Server config:

Service section:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" 
                     name="MyService ">
                <endpoint 
                                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                                bindingConfiguration="netTcpSettings" 
                                name="netTcpEP" 
                                contract="MyContract" />
                <host>
                                <baseAddresses>
                                                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://mycomuter:333" />
                                </baseAddresses>
                </host>
</service>
```

Behavior:

```
<behavior name="serviceBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageEnabled="false" />
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" maxConcurrentSessions="30" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
</behavior>
```

Binding:

```
<binding name="netTcpSettings" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                <security>
                                <transport clientCredentialType="None">
                                                <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"  />
                                </transport>
                                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="TripleDesSha256" />
                </security>
</binding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not just deactivate certificate-validation on the server. Because the clients check if the certificate is valid or not. Sorry to tell you that.

If you want to turn the validation off, you need to type some code for the clients... If you want to, you can just ask how to deactivate / configure the validator on the clients. Its a easy way.

Comment: After a very long negotiation with CA, they agreed to change the structure of their certificate, by performing a "ceremony" (their word not mine), and also with the added cost of 6000$ from my end /: